# Batch file removing folders with date from text file

Tags: date, batch-file, directory

I'm working on a batch file to remove backups with folder name as the current date of backup. All is well so far but I've run into an error I would like to safeguard.

Here is what I have so far.

PART OF BATCH FILE

```
    @ECHO OFF
    :RETRY
    CLS
    d:
    cd\mybackup
    dir /ad /B /o:n > list.txt
    type d:\mybackup\list.txt | find "-"
    ECHO Input year and month to delete and press Enter.
    ECHO i.e. YYYY-MM
    SET "VARIABLE="
    SET /p VARIABLE=
    if not defined VARIABLE echo No date entered?&PAUSE&goto RETRY
    type list.txt|findstr /i /b "%variable%" >nul
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Invalid date entered&PAUSE&goto RETRY
    for /D %%f in (%VARIABLE%*) do rmdir %%f /s /q
    CLS
    ECHO %variable% Backup removed from disk! ! !
    PAUSE
    GOTO MAIN
```

DATES FROM TEXT FILE

```
    2013-07-01
    2013-07-02
    2013-07-03
    2013-07-04
    2013-07-05
    2013-08-09
```

What I have so far will prompt me to enter a date to remove old folders with a wildcard.  If a date is not entered it returns an error and prompts again.  if an date not listed is entered it returns an error and prompts again.  However, if I enter 2013-07 it will remove all folders that contain 2013-07.  If I enter 2013 it will will remove all folders.  I need to somehow make my entered variable as ####-## so it will only remove that format and nothing shorter or longer than what is entered.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There could be an easier solution if all you need to do is keep a certain number of the most recent backups.

Answer (score 0):

you can test it with the help of REGEX, example for `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
echo(%variable%|findstr "^201[0-3]-[0-2][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$" >nul&& echo date format is good || echo wrong date format
```

Comment: Where would I add that in the batch file and what might I change?

Comment: I let it to the OP to figure it out.